# Why is "ゼロ" more popular than "れい"?

Tags: word-choice

For the number zero, `[零]{れい}` is a Chinese origin word that is pretty much familiarized in Japanese. Nevertheless, it seems more popular to use the Western origin word `ゼロ`, which probably appeared later. Why is that? They are both two morae, and I don't see any phonological reason.

Comment: The answers given seem completely reasonable but I wonder also if prestige has anything to do with it.  It seems like there's a fairly high level of prestige associated with using recently borrowed loan words as long as they have been sufficiently disseminated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ゼロ has almost 0% ambiguity (when spoken) and, only requiring katakana, is much easier to write.

Comment: Also, it sounds cooler ;D

Comment: unfortunately, many younger Japanese people seem ignorant about where the word zero comes from and assume it is Japanese.

Comment: Claytonian, that's fair; we stole it from the French, who stole it from the Italians, who stole it from the Arabs, and we probably think it's an English word :). If young people think it's Japanese, and everyone eventually believes them, then it will become true.

Comment: @Pacerier So a little more digging indicates that both the concept and the word (sifr in Arabic) were taken by the Arabs from Sanskrit (sunya), and I remember someone indicating that the Indians may have lifted the concept from the Chinese. But at some point, you're digging around in the dawn of history for a curious cultural game of one-upmanship.

Suffice it to say that humans have been able to conceptualize "nothing" for a very long time, and we should give our ancestors some credit ;).

Comment: The concept of "nothing" is surely very old, but the concept of "zero" as a number is fairly recent *(less than two millennia, at least)*.

Comment: @Claytonian It's famous the origin of zero is India in Japan, I think.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard れい still being used when pronouncing phone numbers.  But other than phone numbers (and maybe sports scores,) ゼロ is generally easier for listeners to pick up [because](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q108328520) it has more of a 濁音{だくおん} (voiced sound.)

More analysis for this can be found on [this page,](http://www.cozymax.org/study/zero050615.htm) as well.

Comment: Interesting hypothesis.

Comment: there's also 零時 (midnight) though it seems somewhat literary, not sure if it's used in everyday speech.

Answer (score 3):

Zero means nothing, but 零 means a quite bit. So 0.5,零細企業 so on. It is said Japanese didn't have a word which means nothing. Well also most Japanese don't know this fact, though.

Answer (score 3):

Like  Takahiro Waki [hinted at](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4047/why-is-%e3%82%bc%e3%83%ad-more-popular-than-%e3%82%8c%e3%81%84/47580#47580) in another answer, 零 originally didn't mean the numeral "zero", nor the idea of "none, empty"; it meant "a little, paltry, small, fraction" (as in 零細{れいさい} = "insignificant", or in Chinese 六十有零 = "a little over sixty").  Up until well into the Edo period, the word doesn't appear as a numeral in Japanese-language texts (it did appear in mathematical treatises of the 和算{わさん} tradition, but these were written in Chinese and of limited influence).  In things like merchant's ledgers, nothingness was represented by a blank.  In other words, Japan was a culture without a numeral zero, just like the West before it was introduced from the Hindo-Arabic tradition (compare with the Roman numerals).

零 as a numeral zero only spread into general usage quite late, possibly as late as Meiji.  So it didn't have that much of a time advantage over the introduction of the word *zero*, which might have facilitated their coexistence (especially since Japanese was already used to multiple numerals for each number).

Source: Yōsuke Hashimoto, *Nihongo no Nazo wo toku*.

Answer (score 2):

れい is also used when saying numbers with a decimal point that begin with a zero.

> 0.5

reads phonetically as

> れい てん  ご

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is relevant, but I have also heard the null-valued numeral written as 〇 and pronounced まる, but I don't know much about this.

Comment: This one is used a lot with apartment numbers, especially when the zero is the middle digit. 201 -> "にまるいち"

Comment: 201号室=にまるいちごうしつ.