# A problem with numbers

Tags: translation, numbers

I ask again today a question that will probably be completely trivial for those who know the language.

What is the difference between 一〇〇四六 and 一万四十六 ?
Or (I think the difference is the same, but I don't know which it is) between 一九〇九〇 and 一万九千九十 ?

Answer (score 3):

一万四十六 is a single number: "ten thousand fourty six".

一〇〇四六 is a sequence of digits: "one, zero, zero, four, six". This would be kanji spelling of things like telephone numbers, which are in modern times rather always spelt using Arabic numerals.

Analogically for 一万九千九十 and 一九〇九〇.

See also: [Is a の said after the first three digtis of 10 phone number?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56516/)

You should also learn [零](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%9B%B6#Japanese) kanji. See: [Why is "ゼロ" more popular than "れい"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4047/), [numbers in Kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59706/).

Comment: A thousand thanks!